# California LLC statement of information filing (LLC-12R)

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, california

I received a notice that my California LLC is required to file another statement of information filing. It requests that I use form `LLC-12R`, however, I can only find `LLC-12` listed on the official secretary of state website (http://www.sos.ca.gov/business-programs/business-entities/forms/). Is the form `LLC-12` the same as `LLC-12R`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forms are almost identical, just formatted slightly differently. I just compared an old copy of an R form with the current one without the R. I don't know why they removed the R. In any case, I filed my biannual this year on llc-12, no "r", and no issues.